# Need help correcting a VBA/Macro code to combine multiple tabs into one

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and have primarily used it in conjunction with creating a macro. As you can see from the code below, I am trying to take tables from three different tabs and merge them into one. However, I am having a hard time understanding how to ensure that each table will paste directly underneath the previous table and not overwrite it (especially when each month new rows are created).

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

```
' Step_4_Combination_Tab Macro

    Sheets("Past Data").Select
    Range("A2:M2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Combination").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A5483").Select
    Sheets("Actual").Select
    Range("A5:M5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Combination").Select
    Range("A5483").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A5483").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A8341").Select
    Sheets("Forecast").Select
    Range("A4:M4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Combination").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code might do what you want:

```
Sub mergeSheets()
    Set targetSheet = Sheets("Combination")
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Name <> "Combination" Then
            Last = LastRow(Sheets("Combination"))
            Sheets(i).UsedRange.Copy targetSheet.Cells(Last + 1, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
End Function
```

some codebits taken from here https://www.exceltip.com/cells-ranges-rows-and-columns-in-vba/copy-the-usedrange-of-each-sheet-into-one-sheet-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the last row that has data and paste you next table there.

```
    LR = Sheets("Combination").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Pasterange = "A" & LR
    Sheets("Combination").Range(Pasterange).Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to copy data from tabs "Past data", "Actual" and "Forecast" to "Consolidated". Am I right? And for some odd reason data in source worksheets begins in different rows. I would do it this way:

```
Sub AllToCons()
CopyToCons "Past data", 2
CopyToCons "Actual", 5
CopyToCons "Forecast", 4
End Sub

Sub CopyToCons(wsName As String, lRow As Long)
'wsName: name of sheet we are copying from
'lRow: number of row where data start

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsCons As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set wsCons = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)

With ws
Set rng = Range(.Range("A" & lRow), .Range("M" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

rng.Copy

With wsCons
.Range("A" & .Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 
End With
```

If you want to paste values only, type xlPasteValues instead of xlPasteAll.
Hope it helped.